# How can I detect if a browser supports the blink tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The HTML `<blink>` tag, in browsers that support it (i.e. Mozilla Firefox and Opera), makes its content blink on and off, resembling the effect of a slow strobe light.

I am writing a suite of polyfills for non-standard HTML, including the `blink` tag. The implementation of blinking behavior is pretty simple

```
(function blink(n) {
    var blinks = document.getElementsByTagName("blink"),
        visibility = n % 2 === 0 ? "visible" : "hidden";
    for (var i = 0; i < blinks.length; i++) {
        blinks[i].style.visibility = visibility;
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        blink(n + 1);
    }, 500);
})(0);
```

(You can [see this in action](http://jsfiddle.net/s2Mgz/3/))

But this does not detect if the browser already supports the `blink` tag, and in browsers that already support it, there will be a double-blinking effect. I need some feature detection that determines if the browser supports blink, and if it doesn't then it falls back on my Javascript polyfill.

I do not want to do browser detection, because that solution is not scalable, and since people can disable `blink` behavior in their Firefox preferences, that solution is not effective.

Is there a way to detect support for the `blink` element?

Comment: Good question, however I didn't think someone used that element. [W3's own wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/blink) states `No, really, don't use it. It's simply evil.`. May I ask what you want to use it for?

Comment: @PeterOlson totally understand .... removing my comment after re-reading your question :-)

Comment: You could just override the behaviour anyway, and replace the element with span, keeping the same content.

Comment: The difficulty is that all the browsers do support the blink tag, they juste disable its particular behaviour.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson Mostly for the purpose of geocities-esque nostalgia.

Comment: @PeterOlson I will not be satisfied until there is a built in tag to do flaming GIF text that blinks while doing a marquee.

Comment: @PeterOlson Well for that purpose it sounds perfect, lol.

Comment: BTW, you should probably use setInterval instead of setTimeout here...

Comment: I think Ben Parsons has the right idea. Instead of trying to detect if it works, just disable any native functionality by changing the element to a span, and then toggle viability for everyone.

Comment: Just wrap it in a `<marquee>` tag. ;)

Comment: @MattHuggins [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/vAMdH/2/)?

Comment: @PeterOlson Here's an update that's not susceptible to integer overflow :P http://jsfiddle.net/vAMdH/3/

Comment: This question is now outdated, since no browser versions that we should care about support the `blink` element.

Comment: While a few older browsers may support it, as of May 2015, users no longer support the tag. (In fact, nearly all are against it.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just did a little research on the matter and *I think* I may found an answer...

I'm sure you're aware of CSS property support detection? Well, there is a `text-decoration: blink` CSS property. So if the browser supports `<blink>` it must support the CSS property too!

This is normal CSS property detection i.e. to detect `textDecoration` is supported do this:

```
if (document.createElement("detect").style.textDecoration === "") {  
    // textDecoration supported
}
```

Perhaps you could try something like this:

```
if (document.createElement("detect").style.textDecoration === "blink") {  
    // textDecoration: blink supported ?
}
```

or along those lines...

## Update

I have 4 browsers & so tested this with 4 browsers. Out of those 4 only FireFox supports the blink tag. `<blink>` is registered in the HTML document as a "Span" element in FF, but in the other 3 browsers it is registered as an `unknown` element.

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function investigate() {
    var blinker = document.getElementsByTagName("blink")[0];
    document.getElementById("monitor").innerHTML += blinker;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="investigate()">
<blink>Hello, blink!</blink>
<div id="monitor"> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

## Output

Internet Explorer [7,8,9] **not supported**

> Hello, blink!
>   [object]

Chrome [18] **not supported**

> Hello, blink!
>   [object HTMLUnknownElement]

Safari [5] **not supported**

> Hello, blink!
>   [object HTMLElement]

FireFox [3.6] **supported**

> Hello, blink!
>   [object HTMLSpanElement]

Comment: It's a good idea, but browsers all support the `textDecoration` property, the problems is that they don't all recognize `blink` as the value of that property. You have given me a few ideas to try out, though...

Comment: Opera also supports `blink`, but it outputs `[object HTMLElement]`. The problem is that the `toString` function for a DOM object is implementation-specific.